# Is Nick's "condition" cured?

Tags: grimm

[Spoilers that continue into the current season, June 2016]

Nick has, on several occasions since his encounter with

> Baron Samedi, turned pale (gone gray), become significantly more difficult to kill, and also much more savage when in a life-or-death situation.

In his recent fights in which he incurs Daredevil-esque levels of damage, it seems as though this condition would have resurfaced, and been quite useful, at that. However, it's been so long since it's happened that I can't even remember the last occurrence. Was this cured at some point without me noticing? Are we to assume it's been cured

> since he found (and handled) the miracle stick?

Or is it likely the condition is still present, to be handled on a later story arc?

Comment: I suppose "the writers forgot" isn't a real reason. ;)

Comment: All of Nick's super abilities come and go at the speed of plot. Like super hearing and super strength / stamina from zombie guy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After Nick becomes a Grimm again, we see him turn grey for a moment in *S4E6: Highway of Tears*. The last time we see him go grey is 3 episodes later in *S4E9: Wesenrein.*

Since we don't see it happen again over the next year and a half, despite the numerous times Nick is angry or injured or exercising or sleeping (or whatever brings on the episodes) we might conclude that he eventually became cured of the condition.

Comment: Or, the writers hoped we'd forget.